# Changing ContentChildren models on QueryList.changes

Tags: javascript, angular

Suppose I have a parent component with `@ContentChildren(Child) children`.  Suppose that each `Child` has an `index` field within its component class.  I'd like to keep these `index` fields up-to-date when the parent's children change, doing something as follows:

```
this.children.changes.subscribe(() => {
  this.children.forEach((child, index) => {
    child.index = index;
  })
});
```

However, when I attempt to do this, I get an "ExpressionChangedAfter..." error, I guess due to the fact that this `index` update is occurring outside of a change cycle.  Here's a stackblitz demonstrating this error: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-brjjrl.

How can I work around this?  One obvious way is to simply bind the `index` in the template.  A second obvious way is to just call `detectChanges()` for each child when you update its index.  Suppose I can't do either of these approaches, is there another approach?

Comment: I know you said you cannot use `detectChanges()` and folks below suggest `setTimeout`. I just wanted to point out that unless you cannot bind to an input, `detectChanges()` would be the proper way to do this and `setTimeout` would fail if you would switch to `OnPush` change detection strategy (which I am a huge advocate of).

Comment: Yeah, I'm also an OnPush advocate.  I love how many people recommend setTimeout, I don't really consider it a proper fix... partially for the reason you mention, partially for the subsequent visual flicker if rendering depends upon index, etc...

Comment: I always prefer markForCheck over detectChanges wherever possible. You could make input a setter and call markForCheck in it, this way your deeper component would be responsible for syncing change detection which is what you probably prefer judging by your comments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As stated, the error comes from the value changing after the change cycle has evaluated `<div>{{index}}</div>`.

> More specifically, the view is using your local component variable `index` to assign `0`... which is then changed as a new item is pushed to the array... your subscription sets the true index for the previous item only after, it has been created and added to the DOM with an index value of `0`.

---

The `setTimout` or `.pipe(delay(0))` (these are essentially the same thing) work because it keeps the change linked to the change cycle that `this.model.push({})` occurred in... where without it, the change cycle is already complete, and the 0 from the previous cycle is changed on the new/next cycle when the button is clicked.

Set a duration of `500` ms to the setTimeout approach and you will see what it is truly doing.

```
 ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.foos.changes.pipe(delay(0)).subscribe(() => {
      this.foos.forEach((foo, index) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          foo.index = index;
        }, 500)
      });
    });
  }
```

- It does indeed allow the value to be set after the element is rendered on
  the DOM while avoiding the error however, you will not have the value
  available in the component during the constructor or `ngOnInit` if
  you need it.

The following in `FooComponent` will always result in `0` with the `setTimeout` solution.

```
ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.index)
  }
```

> Passing the index as an input like below, will make the value
>   available during the constructor or `ngOnInit` of `FooComponent`

---

You mention not wanting to bind to the index in the template, but it unfortunately would be the only way to pass the index value prior to the element being rendered on the DOM with a default value of `0` in your example.

You can accept an input for the index inside of the `FooComponent`

```
export class FooComponent  {
  // index: number = 0;
  @Input('index') _index:number;
```

Then pass the index from your loop to the input

```
<foo *ngFor="let foo of model; let i = index" [index]="i"></foo>
```

Then use the input in the view

```
selector: 'foo',
  template: `<div>{{_index}}</div>`,
```

> This would allow you to manage the index at the `app.component` level via the `*ngFor`, and pass it into the new element on the DOM as it is rendered... essentially avoiding the need to assign the index to the component variable, and also ensuring the `true` index is provided when the change cycle needs it, at the time of render / class initialization.

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ozfpsr?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: What's too bad about this solution is that if I'm building a component library and someone is using my FooComponent, they *should not have to bind index in their template for FooComponent to work*.  FooComponent should be able to figure it out on its own.  I suppose this is not yet possible in Angular.

Comment: The `model` array living in the `app.component` and not being passed as an input to the `FooComponent`,  certainly does pose some unique challenges. I am sure there is a legitimate reason for this structure, but if you were able to pass `model` as an input to your `FooComponent` for example, you would certainly be able to make the component "figure it out" on its own so to speak. This is a standard approach passing an array to a library component input, the `mat-table` of the material library for example requires a `[dataSource]` input. Anyone using your library would understand this approach.

Comment: Maybe you can optionally inject ngFor in your component to see if it's in a loop and figure out its position in it somehow from that?

Answer (score 3):

One way is update the index value using a Macro-Task. This is essentially a `setTimeout`, but bear with me.

This makes your subscription from your StackBlitz look like this:

```js
ngAfterContentInit() {
  this.foos.changes.subscribe(() => {

    // Macro-Task
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.foos.forEach((foo, index) => {
        foo.index = index;
      });
    }, 0);

  });
}
```

Here is a [working StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bxrn1e).

So the javascript event loop is coming into play. The reason for the "ExpressionChangedAfter..." error is highlighting the fact that changes are being made to other components which essentially mean that another cycle of change detection *should* run otherwise you can get inconsistent results in the UI. That's something to avoid.

What this boils down to is that if we want to update something, but we *know* it shouldn't cause other side-effects, we can schedule something in the Macro-Task queue. When the change detection process is finished, only then will the next task in the queue be executed.

---

**Resources**

The whole event loop is there in javascript because there is only a single-thread to play with, so it's useful to be aware of what's going on.

This [article from Always Be Coding](https://abc.danch.me/microtasks-macrotasks-more-on-the-event-loop-881557d7af6f) explains the Javascript Event Loop much better, and goes into the details of the micro/macro queues.

For a bit more depth and running code samples, I found the post from Jake Archibald very good: [Tasks, microtasks, queues and schedules](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/)

Comment: never use timeout in an angular project

Comment: Whilst I agree my answer is not the best for this scenario (use `delay()`, or use an `@Input()`), there are scenarios where timeout/macro task is needed. This is javascript at the end of the day; Angular project or not, you need to know this stuff.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you are changing something after the view generation process is further modifying the data it is trying to display in the first place. The ideal place to change would be in the **life-cycle hook before the view is displayed**, but another issue arises here i.e., `this.foos` is `undefined` when these hooks are called as QueryList is only populated before `ngAfterContentInit`.

Unfortunately, there aren't many options left at this point. [@matt-tester](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55345785/1525163) detailed explanation of micro/macro task is a very helpful resource to understand why the hacky `setTimeout` works.

But the solution to an Observable is using more observables/operators (pun intended), so piping a delay operator is a cleaner version in my opinion, as `setTimeout` is encapsulated within it.

```js
ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.foos.changes.pipe(delay(0)).subscribe(() => {
        this.foos.forEach((foo, index) => {
          foo.index = index;
        });
    });
}
```

here is the [working version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-puzcz6)

Comment: It would be nice if there was on overload for the operator which made it more readable. `delay(0)` reads poorly compared to something like `macroTask()` (or something). Otherwise, I like the cleanliness.

Comment: You can always alias import delay with whatever name you prefer, ex., `import { delay as microTask } from 'rxjs/operators';`

Answer (score 1):

use below code, to make that changes in the next cycle

```
this.foos.changes.subscribe(() => {

  setTimeout(() => {
    this.foos.forEach((foo, index) => {
      foo.index = index;
    });
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know the kind of application, but to avoid playing with ordered indexes , it is often a good idea to use uid's as index.
Like this, there is no need to renumber indexes when you add or remove components since they are unique.
You maintain only a list of uids in the parent.

another solution that  may solve your problem , by dynamically creating your components  and thus maintain a list of these childs components in the parent .

regarding the example you provided on stackblitz (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bxrn1e) , it can be easily solved without monitoring changes :

replace with the following code :

app.component.html

```
<hello [(model)]="model">
  <foo *ngFor="let foo of model;let i=index" [index]="i"></foo>
</hello>
```

hello.component.ts

- remove changes monitoring
- added foocomponent index parameter

  import { ContentChildren, ChangeDetectorRef, Component, Input, Host, Inject, forwardRef, QueryList } from '@angular/core';

  ```
  @Component({
    selector: 'foo',
    template: `<div>{{index}}</div>`,
  })
  export class FooComponent  {
    @Input() index: number = 0;

    constructor(@Host() @Inject(forwardRef(()=>HelloComponent)) private hello) {}

    getIndex() {
      if (this.hello.foos) {
        return this.hello.foos.toArray().indexOf(this);
      }

      return -1;
    }
  }

  @Component({
    selector: 'hello',
    template: `<ng-content></ng-content>
      <button (click)="addModel()">add model</button>`,
  })
  export class HelloComponent  {
    @Input() model = [];
    @ContentChildren(FooComponent) foos: QueryList<FooComponent>;

    constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}



    addModel() {
      this.model.push({});
    }
  }
  ```

I forked this working implementation : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uwad8c